# Using a simple tree inside a Linguex environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, linguistics, linguex, movement-arrows

I'm trying to copy of linguistic rule by Zubizarreta (1998) (see attached picture). I would like to provide a minimal example but I'm lost...

[image]

I'd like to use a linguex environment and tikzpicture inside. I found the package "movement-arrows" that could draw the arrow in the lower sentence but not the vertical ones. I am willing to learn something but I don't know where to find a hint or even an answer.

Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `movement-arrows` package to mark the relevant words and then add other annotations manually using TikZ. Here's your example. If you're doing this a lot, there would be ways to make it more automatic, but for small numbers of examples this should do the trick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{movement-arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand\tsub{\textsubscript}
\begin{document}
\ex. P-movement (subject focus)
\a. \arrowstrut\arrowstrut* \mkword[juan-a]{[Juan]\tsub{F}} compró una \mkword{bicicleta}
\b. \arrowstrut\arrowstrut\mkword[vp]{[\tsub{VP} Compró una bicicleta ]}\mkword[juan]{[Juan]\tsub{F}} \mkword[t]{t\tsub{VP}}
\mvarrow{t}{vp}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \node  [above= .5cm of juan-a.north] (FPR) {FPR};
    \node [above=.5cm of bicicleta] (NSR) {NSR};
    \draw[thick,->] (FPR) -- (juan-a);
    \draw[thick,->] (NSR) -- (bicicleta);
    \node [above=.5cm of juan.north west] (FPR2) {FPR};
    \node [above=.5cm of juan.north east] (NSR2) {NSR};
    \draw [thick,->] (FPR2) -- (juan);
    \draw [thick,->] (NSR2) -- (juan);
    }
    
\end{document}
```

You need to compile twice for the annotations to be added correctly.

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the code! It helps a lot in understanding the concept. 
Usually I need standard examples that are much easier.

Comment: The snippets works like a charm on its own but I use another document class (scrbook). The result of the code does not work properly - even after a couple of compilations. The tikzpictures is compressed to the lower right corner. Is that somehow related to the document class?

Comment: @sanpii It's unlikely to be the document class itself (if I change this example to scrbook it works the same) so it's more likely to be something different that you are doing in your actual document. If you can reproduce the example with a minimal example the you could ask another question about that problem specifically (or you may end up discovering what the problem is.)